# mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar NOT deployed

Tags: java, netbeans

I am coding my first web app in java and got stuck in db stuff. Followed two tutorials (ref: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html and part1:http://www.javaguicodexample.com/javawebmysqljspjstljsf5.html part2: http://www.javaguicodexample.com/javawebmysqljspjstljsf5_1.html) and got the same issue regarding db config. Crosschecked multiple times and found that mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar is there in the desired path and configured properly but is not deployed on running the app. Due to this getting TABLE/VIEW not found.

Kindly help as I am debugging by crosschecking the steps of the provided manuals but its not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving "TABLE/VIEW not found" that means application is successful in making database connection. There is no such table/view exists in the database.

Regarding dependencies, I would suggest to use some build tool like [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or gradle to make sure all dependencies and versions are managed properly